# Wont allow me to create more than 1 LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to create LineRenderers at runtime(when the user presses a button).

**My Problem:** I can never create more than one LineRenderer. When I go to created the 2nd one, the LineRenderer object is always NULL.

What am I doing wrong? **Can you provide advice on what I need to do to create more than one LineRenderer?**

```
public class AppInit : MonoBehaviour {

        public Vector3[] TEST_VERTICES;
        public const int SPEED = 5;
        public List<LineRenderer> lines;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
             TEST_VERTICES = new Vector3[10] {new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(10,10,10), new Vector3(30,10,50), new Vector3(30,40,50), 
                                                                            new Vector3(10,30,90), new Vector3(10,20,40), new Vector3(50,20,40), new Vector3(70,80,90), 
                                                                            new Vector3(10,70,20), new Vector3(60,10,0)};
             lines = new List<LineRenderer>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
             float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * SPEED;
             float z = 0;
             float y = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")   * Time.deltaTime * SPEED;

             gameObject.transform.Translate (new Vector3(x,y,z));
        }

        void OnGUI() {
             if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,10,100,20), "Create"))
                 createString(TEST_VERTICES);
        }

        public bool createString( Vector3[] vertices ) {
             LineRenderer lRend = gameObject.AddComponent ("LineRenderer") as LineRenderer;
             //LineRenderer lRend = new LineRenderer();
             lines.Add(lRend);
             Debug.Log ("IS NULL"+(lRend == null).ToString ());
             lRend.SetColors (new Color(100,0,0,100), new Color(0,0,100,100));
             lRend.SetWidth(10, 1);
             lRend.SetVertexCount(vertices.Length);

             for (int i=0; i<vertices.Length; i++)
                 lRend.SetPosition(i, vertices[i]);

             return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear by specifying where exactly you are getting null object. Have you tried debugging the code ? when you press second time try checking the values.

Comment: Use the generic form of AddComponent.

Comment: If you cannot add a second component of the same type, than it should be clear you have to add a second gameobject with the linerenderer....
Please mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

As Iridium points out, you can only add one component of each type to a gameobject. So you want to create a new game object for each new linerenderer. The simple way to do this here is to change:

```
LineRenderer lRend = gameObject.AddComponent("LineRenderer") as LineRenderer;
```

to:

```
LineRenderer lRend = new GameObject().AddComponent("LineRenderer") as LineRenderer;
```

Then if you need to access the linerenderer's gameobject later you can do so by lRend.gameObject. Or lines[index].gameObject.

Comment: Addition: As far as I know, you can add more than one component of the same type to a GameObject. But in this case the restriction is, that there can only be Renderer for a GameObject.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google brings up this page: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47575/create-a-linerender-in-c.html which suggests that you cannot add multiple instances of the same type to a single `GameObject`, and suggests that multiple `GameObject` instances should be used instead.